# Javascript loop with out blocking thread

Tags: javascript

I'm working directly with the javascript engine JavascriptCore so there is not a "window" object to use for example setInterval, setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame. So my question is how can I do a loop without blocking the thread with a pure javascript code?

For example this code :

```
while(true) {  // UH OH! - blocks thread
  update();
  render();
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: First Google Search: http://isaacsukin.com/news/2015/01/detailed-explanation-javascript-game-loops-and-timing

Comment: That depends on your host environment.

Comment: @Cristy: He doesn't have a DOM.

Comment: Then his question should be this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100190/using-setinterval-settimeout-in-javascriptcore-framework-for-objectivec

Comment: What do `update()` and `render()` do, because they are what's blocking the thread, not the loop itself.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using setInterval, setTimeout in JavascriptCore Framework for ObjectiveC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100190/using-setinterval-settimeout-in-javascriptcore-framework-for-objectivec)

Comment: Or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991044/ios-implemention-of-window-settimeout-with-javascriptcore

Comment: @Cristy your first answer is attached to DOM object so doesn't work.

Comment: @Cristy I wanted to know a pure javascript answer because I implemented a setTimeout function in C++ and I bound it to JSCore to emulate the window.setTimeOutBehaviour like the ObjectiveC solution

Comment: @ScottMarcus update and render are examples sorry. I should use doSomething(). And just to be clear if you run and infinite loop in the js console of any browser and even better if you run it in any js engine like jscore or v8 that piece of code is gonna block the thread or at least the CPU is gonna be hotter than ever :)

Comment: That’s why I asked what the functions did - possibly breaking the loop.

Comment: @AlexisBarra Check the questions I linked about using setTimeout in JSCore.